# Mondrian non-star schema, multiple fact tables

Tags: pentaho, olap, mondrian

Is there a way to create a Cube in Mondrian Pentaho without a Star Schema? I tried to create a Cube with non-start schema, but I cannot export the Schema file for that and cannot customize the Dimensions.

More precisely I want to define multiple fact tables.

Comment: I want to add multiple fact tables. So far I saw I have possibility to add Virtual Cubes in Schema Workbench, but I don't see how to add fact table to virtual cube ...

Comment: You want multiple fact tables in one cube? That is not possible.

Comment: In icCube for example you can have multiple fact tables in a cube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mondrian the Cube definition only defines one Table. So all your facts has to come from this single table.

To include facts from different tables you need to use a database view. Either a native view in your database or a [Mondrian View](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/xml_schema.php#View).

I experienced massive performance differences between using a native view and a Mondrian View, because of how Mondrian structures it's SQL queries. I recommend native database views.